# Record audio output

Tags: raspbian, audio

Is there any way to record the audio output on the raspberry pi from the command line? I have tried using arecord, but it says the Pi doesn't have any audio capture cards. I also want to be able to redirect the raw audio to stdout.

Comment: Could you post the exact command you are using and the exact error you are getting? That would help us a lot :) Also, check out this [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224748) post on how to record audio going to the speakers from the command-line. It should be somewhat if not totally compatible with the Raspberry Pi, as they are both debian-based.

Comment: As this is more of a linux than RPi specific question, you could ask it on superuser to get more attention and eyes on the problem

Answer (score -2):

You do not state that you require a software only solution, considering the cost and ease I would recommend a hardware solution.

The raspberry Pi does not have a microphone. Common solution is to purchase a cheap USB sound card with mic socket. I have one that works fine that cost under £10 from Amazon. Alternately there are extension boards that offer high fidelity for the Pi at the cost of using the GPIO pins and costing substantial more.

Comment: -1, the question explicitly asks for recording audio output, e.g. what you can hear when connecting speakers, not input.